# Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/css/swiper.css'

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

When I upgrade version `swiper^5.2.0` to `swiper^8.1.4` then facing issue `Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/css/swiper.css'`

Also When I import `import 'swiper/css';` then facing `Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/css'`

react version 16.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Create React App doesn't support pure ESM packages yet. [See the swiper documention for a workaround.](https://swiperjs.com/react#usage-with-create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

inside your react component, import this -

```
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';
```

hope its will work...